# text hover hyper link

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display a text as I hover specific divs. When I hover, I get the text on hover, but it flickers. Right now I have that text that appears on two divs(DIV 2 and DIV 3). As I switch from div 2 to div 3, I get the text saying "click me!". But if I keep my cursor on that text "click me!", it starts to flicker.

my onMouseOver and onMouseOut function are

```
function mouseOverFunc2()
{
    {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
        newDiv.setAttribute("id","id_span");
        newDiv.innerText = " -- click me!";
        div2.appendChild(newDiv);
        console.log(div2);
    }
}

function mouseOverFunc3()
{
    {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
        newDiv.setAttribute("id","id_span");
        newDiv.innerText = " -- click me!";
        div3.appendChild(newDiv);
        console.log(div1);
    }
}
```

```js
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var div3 = document.getElementById("div3");

div2.onmouseover = mouseOverFunc2;
div2.onmouseout = mouseOutFunc2;

div3.onmouseover = mouseOverFunc3;
div3.onmouseout = mouseOutFunc3;

function mouseOverFunc2()
{
  {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id","id_span");
    newDiv.innerText = " -- click me!";
    div2.appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log(div2);
  }
}

function mouseOverFunc3()
{
  {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id","id_span");
    newDiv.innerText = " -- click me!";
    div3.appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log(div1);
  }
}

function mouseOutFunc2()
{
  var node = document.getElementById("id_span");
  if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}

function mouseOutFunc3()
{
  var node = document.getElementById("id_span");
  if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="divv" title="asda"></div>
<div id="div1">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div2">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div3">DIV 3</div>
<div id="div4">DIV 4</div>
<div id="div5">DIV 5</div>
```

Comment: why don't use just `CSS` ?

Comment: The tool that I work on does not support latest styling. But I would like to know how it can be done by using css.

Comment: just the `:hover` pseudo-class and it is supported in all browsers nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`. the difference?

> "Though similar to mouseover, it differs in that it doesn't bubble and
>   that it isn't sent to any descendants when the pointer is moved from
>   one of its descendants' physical space to its own physical space."

```js
var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
var div3 = document.getElementById("div3");

div2.onmouseenter = mouseOverFunc2;
div2.onmouseleave = mouseOutFunc2;

div3.onmouseenter = mouseOverFunc3;
div3.onmouseleave = mouseOutFunc3;

function mouseOverFunc2() {
  {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "id_span");
    newDiv.innerText = " -- click me!";
    div2.appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log(div2);
  }
}

function mouseOverFunc3() {
  {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("span");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "id_span");
    newDiv.innerText = " -- click me!";
    div3.appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log(div1);
  }
}

function mouseOutFunc2() {
  var node = document.getElementById("id_span");
  if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}

function mouseOutFunc3() {
  var node = document.getElementById("id_span");
  if (node.parentNode) {
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="divv" title="asda"></div>
<div id="div1">DIV 1</div>
<div id="div2">DIV 2</div>
<div id="div3">DIV 3</div>
<div id="div4">DIV 4</div>
<div id="div5">DIV 5</div>
```

Comment: Why not just give each div a title attribute?

Answer (score 0):

It really sounds like a `title` attribute would be the best bet, especially in terms of accessibility and cross browser functionality—here are the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title).

However if you want something with more flexibility, I'd consider a using a library such as [Tippy](https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs)